# Rails 3 - vote_fu - Collection of User Votes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Using the vote_fu plugin for rails 3, I'm struggling with something (that I think) should be pretty easy, but didn't see while reading the documentation.

What I'm trying to do is creating a collection of all the objects a user has voted on.

In my case, I only have Users (voters), and Links(voteables). I want to create a collection for a specific user of everything they've voted for.

I'm really just trying to get this collection working in the console at this point, has anyone been able to create this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More coffee helped along with me decided to not be an idiot.

Get a collection of my user votes so:

```
@votes = current_user.votes
```

Then loop through the array to display information about the voteables, example:

```
<% @votes.each do |vote| %>
<%= vote.voteable.title %><br />
<% end %>
```